# How to use the functions:glRenderMode(GLenum mode),glSelectBuffer(GLsizei size, GLuint* buffer) in Opengl ES With Android NDK?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am writing an Android App that transplanted from Pc,in the App i used the Opengl ES with common functions Pc,but now have two methods:

```
int glRenderMode(GLenum mode);

void glSelectBuffer(GLsizei size, GLuint* buffer);
```

Those methods are unavailable in ES,I want those methos can usable in Android NDK's ES instead of made to order ES same as [Gish](https://github.com/EXL/Gish) or [gl4es](https://github.com/ptitSeb/gl4es),that will make my project be serious invaded.

So,i hope you can provide me a feasible solution only is based on primary Opengl ES.

I await your Help!

---

I want use the  glRenderMode and glSelectBuffer to select 3D model.

My English is poor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Those methods are unavailable in ES, I want those methods can usable
>   in Android NDK's ES instead

As you have noted, they are not supported in OpenGL ES.

OpenGL ES 3.0 onwards does support transform feedback (equivalent of `GL_FEEDBACK`), but has no equivalent of `GL_SELECT`. It's a bit fiddly to get working, so hard to give a concise answer - but the specification is here:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_es.php#specs3